# From Stata to R parsing issue

Tags: r, stata

I have a problem reading Stata files in R with the haven package. I have seen a few discussions about this on this board but no answer seems to work here.

```
download.file("http://economics.mit.edu/files/3828", "nswre74.dta")
download.file("http://economics.mit.edu/files/3824", "cps1re74.dta")
download.file("http://economics.mit.edu/files/3825", "cps3re74.dta")

nswre74  <- read_dta("nswre74.dta") 
cps1re74 <- read_dta("cps1re74.dta") 
cps3re74 <- read_dta("cps3re74.dta")
```

cps1re74 works but for the two others I obtain the following error :

> nswre74  <- read_dta("C:/Users/nicot/Downloads/nswre74.dta")
> Error in df_parse_dta_file(spec, encoding, cols_skip, n_max, skip, name_repair = .name_repair) :
> Failed to parse C:/Users/nicot/Downloads/nswre74.dta: The provided note is too long for the file format.

I have tried with package foreign.  I have also tried encoding with Latin1 or UTF-8 but nothing seems to work...

Comment: I can see the first which is a very small dataset saved in 2007, so neither the size nor the date should imply any problem. I don't use R routinely so can't comment on R functions.

Comment: See if readstata13 package works.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck No does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

using haven (v. 2.4.1) works for me. (R version 4.0.5)

```
library(haven) 
nswre74  <- read_dta("nswre74.dta") 
cps1re74 <- read_dta("cps1re74.dta") 
cps3re74 <- read_dta("cps3re74.dta")
```

```
> nswre74 %>% head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  treat   age    ed black  hisp married nodeg  re74  re75   re78  age2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    37    11     1     0       1     1     0     0  9930.  1369
2     1    22     9     0     1       0     1     0     0  3596.   484
3     1    30    12     1     0       0     0     0     0 24909.   900
> cps1re74 %>% head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  treat   age    ed black  hisp married nodeg  re74  re75   re78  age2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    37    11     1     0       1     1     0     0  9930.  1369
2     1    22     9     0     1       0     1     0     0  3596.   484
3     1    30    12     1     0       0     0     0     0 24909.   900
> cps3re74%>% head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  treat   age    ed black  hisp married nodeg  re74  re75   re78  age2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    37    11     1     0       1     1     0     0  9930.  1369
2     1    22     9     0     1       0     1     0     0  3596.   484
3     1    30    12     1     0       0     0     0     0 24909.   900
>
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reasons, it still does not work on my side...

Comment: are you using haven to read the file? which version? do you have access to stata? You could try to open the file in stata and remove the note, which seems to be too long. Or update haven to the latest version, which is working fine for me.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have Stata. I am indeed using read_dta from haven !

Comment: which version? I believe with a new version it will work